# multiple private ledgers

Tags: private-blockchain

I'm thinking to create a server-less backbone for the wellness tracking app we are working on (https://sentimoto.com) with the following main principles:

- every user generates his own blockchain of his data
- this blockchain can be shared to a number of users (i.e. users may have access to multiple)

Basically it means that the distributed proof-of-work is not necessary as each user can write only to one (his own) blockchain, but other Ethereum technologies seem to be a good fit.

The questions are:

- what do you think about the idea?
- are ethereum technologies appropriate for this project (and state of maturity are they)?
- is any other project better for this purpose?

Sincerely
Max

Comment: i think you are not working whith blockchains